# RegEx is matching too early

Tags: php, regex, pcre

could anyone help me with a RegEx?
I want to delete all unneccessary information in the artivle title of beverage like size, quantity, and so on.

I made this RegEx: `/(?<!^)(\d{1,2}\s?x\s?)?\d{1,2}((,|\.)\d{1,2})?\s?L?/igU`

On `25 Test Drink 60% 12x1,0L` it's matching the `5` the `25`.

On `Test Drink 60% 12x1,0L` it's matching the `60` before the `%`.

How can I avoid these example? I want to match only the `12x1,0L`. I had to put so many optional characters, because the data source is very inconsistent on the format for the quantity and size. It can also happen that the quantity is missing, because it's only a single bottle/can.

I've provided more example titles below and here: https://regex101.com/r/aQ2kO8/2

> 25 Test Drink 60% 12x1,0L
>   Test Drink 60% 2x0,5
>   Test Drink 3 x 0,75 L
>   Test Drink 4x0,75 L
>   Test Drink 5 x 0,75L
>   Test Drink 66 x 0,75
>   Test Drink 0,75
>   Test Drink 0.75
>   7UP 12 x 1 L

Could someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Could you give `(?:\d+\s*x\s*)?(?:\d+[.,])?\d+\s*L?\s*$` a try? Not sure if I got all your requirements correctly.

Comment: Is it like the pattern you are looking should always end with `L` ?

Comment: @SebastianProske Thanks for the suggestions, but it's only matching for the last example in my link. I added the `?` because these characters are only optional and may not occur in the title. Please check the link where I provided more examples for the titles

Comment: use \m modifier in regex101 if you want to test it for multiple lines. https://regex101.com/r/iN2vD5/1

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I would be happy, if yes. Unfortunately, the guys did not provide it always. Please check the link with more examples of article titles.

Comment: The examples are okay, but it would be great if you mention for each of the title what you expect to be matched. Even if I come up with a regex I can use that to validate

Comment: @nu11p01n73R From my examples: Everything after the actual name of the drink. In this Case `Test Drink`

Comment: @MichaelWalter: https://regex101.com/r/pY1pP0/1

Comment: @SebastianProske: It looks like to work with it. Thank you very much. I will make some researches to understand your version of the RegEx

Comment: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fFj `preg_match("/(\d+\%\s)?((\d+)\s{0,1}x\s{0,1}(\d+,\d+|\d+)|(\d+[,|\.?]\d+)).*/", $in, $out);` ?

Comment: Could not edit my previous. This is better at getting "L". http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fFk `preg_match("/(\d+\%\s)?((\d+)\s{0,1}x\s{0,1}(\d+,\d+|\d+)|(\d+[,|\.?]\d+))\s{0,1}([A-Z]?)/", $in, $out);` ?

Comment: If you can't make a regex that could reliably parse each variation and be confident that you could save the data parts, then you should not even attempt such a regex. It's like you made 2 long heavy duty chains to pull a tree stump out, then joined them with zip ties. Make a regex to go along with the certainty level. If you don't, you will inevitably miss a variant. Here is what you know: _Starts with a number, goes to end of line_. `(?<!\S)\d[\dx., ]*L?[ ]*$` https://regex101.com/r/aQ2kO8/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(?:\d+\s*x\s*)?(?:\d+[.,])?\d+\s*L?\s*$` as a search pattern, you have to set the m- and g-modifier, if you aply it to a multiline text. Also i-modifier might be needed if you don't care for the char-case of `l` and `x`

- `(?:\d+\s*x\s*)?` optionally matches digits followed by an `x` which might be surrounded by spaces
- `(?:\d+[.,])?` optionally matches digits followed by a dot or comma
- `\d+` matches one or more numbers
- `\s*L?\s*` optionally matches a `L` which might be surrounded by spaces
- `$` matches the end of the line. From your description the things you want to match are always at the end, by using this we can avoid matching numbers in the drinks name

Take a look at a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/iN2vD5/1).